# IIS Website with multiple web applications underneath and different ports?

Tags: iis

I am relatively new at configuring IIS and am wondering if the following scenario is possible.

My application consists of 2 Web apps.  1 is an ASP.NET Core App that hosts a Javascript SPA.  I have a second MVC App that is a combined Authorization Server using OpenIddict and the main API that the SPA talks to.

On my dev machine these 2 apps run on different ports.

These 2 apps go together to make our solution for any given customer.  I can get this all working on IIS treating each app as it's own website with it's own port.

But I would like to be able to bundle these 2 apps under 1 website.  Ultimately we will have several customer websites and each "website" really consists of these 2 apps bundled together.

I understand that I can create a single website and then convert my 2 existing sites to a web application.  So 2 web apps sit under the main web site. But these all will run under the same port.

I would really like my API and Authserver to run on a different port.  Is there a way to each this type of scenario?

What is the recommended best practice for what I am describing?

I do not want the API / Auth Server project to be shared by all the customer sites.  I want each customer site to have it's own instance of the Authorization server and API.

It would be great if you could create 2 websites and then sort of group them into a parent website container (if that makes any sense).

Answer (score 0):

You can create two [applications](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042(v=ws.10).aspx) within your website on IIS. Then each application would be accessed as http://customerwebsite/app1 and http://customerwebsite/app2

Comment: Probably want to put a bit more detail into your answers. An answer should provide the solution to the problem without following external links.